# ElasticSearch returns Not a Number (NaN)_on a long works fine on a double

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a shell script which makes a curl call to an ElasticSearch cluster. In the curl request, I have some aggregations with percentiles. The percentiles are calculated as expected when the field is a double, but the results are NaN (Not a Number) when calculated on a long. Am I missing something or Does this sound like a data quality issue?

Comment: Can you share the complete query and aggregation? Also, what ES version is this?

Comment: I meant to respond but found this late in the night. I was not addressing the variable in the JSON nested structure inaccurately (i.e. directly accessing the variable without the reference to the parent).  My bad for doing that, but I wonder why ES did not give me an error as "No such object or attribute" rather kept telling me that the referenced attribute is "not a number"